# Beamer (Latex) Customized Formats

Tags: beamer, formatting, beamerposter, beamerarticle

I hereby attached a pdf snapshot of a sample Beamer Copy
Will you please suggest me how to get this output in Latex

[image: Sample Image]
I am looking forward to your support. 
Thank you

Comment: Looks like a standard beamertheme (i.e. Darmstadt) with changed colors and an added logo. See here: http://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/

Comment: I see lots of missing characters. Is that intended?

Comment: @cfr Most probably, for confidentiality issues, the OP censored some of the letters/words of the original title page, but left enough information to convey the desired layout.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Hmmm. It would be less confusing to just put something fake in its place. Especially with all those odd bits which look like random back ticks. I'm sure you are right, though.

Comment: I intentionally did this. As this file may be copyrighted material. Thus I intentionally discarded few characters. Dear schmendrich, Its true that it is close to Darmstadt beamertheme. They customized it. I dont know how to do this customization in the themes. Firstly they customized the top sections. Then the colors. I dont know how to make it. Please suggest me with a modified Beamer theme coding. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar to this one.
How to make it useful similar to the sample given above

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usetheme{Dresden}
\usecolortheme{whale}
\usecolortheme[rgb={0,0.4,0}]{structure}
\useoutertheme{smoothbars}
\useinnertheme{circles}

\title[ja kajf kajf aelkf afha ljflkahd fahsf hakfh ahfa fha f \hspace{8cm} jlafh  ahfja hfjah  l ]{foiahj fhajkfh jkdahf dhajfhad h \\ Hfha jhfjahs fjkahd fhadjkfh }
\author[fahdifhdahfg dahfguahed  \hspace{4cm}EEE-affead471/ETE-fafa/CEG-485 (LAB\#3) ]{sdhfiadhsfhadi}
\institute [\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber]{ sfhdjfhqajhfjadhfa gsdfdafa  \\
afahfjashfas jfhajhfadhsd University \\
jfhdjahsjfhada, hfjdgafada-1229. 
}


\pgfdeclareimage[width = 20mm]{nsulogo}{DARPA-seeks-human-brain-like-computers-for-complex-signal-processing-and-data-analysis-610x400.jpg}
\logo{\pgfuseimage{nsulogo}}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Background Theory}

\begin{frame} {The Sampling Theorem}
\subsection{Frequency ?}
Question: Given any Analog signal, how should we select the Sampling Period T or, equivalently, the Sampling Rate Fs ? 
\begin{beamerboxesrounded} {\textit - ANSWER ?? }
\begin{itemize}
\item (1) To answer this we must have some general information concerning the FREQUENCY content of the SIGNAL
 \item (2) If we know the Maximum Frequency content of the Signals we can specify the sampling rate necessary to convert the analog signals to digital signals. 
\end{itemize}
\end{beamerboxesrounded}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Analog Signal Representation}
\subsection{Analog Signal Representation}
\begin{beamerboxesrounded}{Analog Signal Representation}
Let us suppose that any analog signal can be represented as a sum of sinusoids of different amplitudes, frequencies and phases using the following equation
\begin{equation}
  x_{a}(t) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} A_{i}cos(2\pi F_{i}t+\Theta_{i})
\end{equation}
\end{beamerboxesrounded}
where,\\
N represents the Number of Frequency Components
\\
\begin{itemize}
\item What is $\ F_{max} ??? $
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\section{Sampling}
\begin{frame}{Determining Sampling Rate}
\subsection{Determining Sampling Rate}
\begin{itemize}
\item If we know the $ F_{max} $ we can select the appropriate sampling rate.
\item The highst frequency in an analog signal that can be unambiguously reconstructed when the signal is sampled at a rate $F_s=\frac{1}{T} $ is $\frac{ F_s}{2}$
\item Frequency Range $-\frac{ F_s}{2} \leq F\leq \frac{F_s}{2} $
\item To avoid ambiguities resulting from aliasing, we need to select the sampling rate to be significantly High
\item we must select $\frac{ F_s}{2} $ to be grater than $ F_{max}$.
\item thus, to avoid ALIASING we $F_s > 2\times F_{max}$
\item $-\frac{1}{2}\leq f_i = \frac{F_i}{F_s}\leq \frac{1}{2} $ or  $ -\pi \leq \omega_i=2 \times \pi \times f_i \leq \pi $
\\since $|f|= \frac{1}{2} or |\omega|=\pi$ is the highest frequency in discrete  time signal
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Determining Sampling Rate}
\subsection{Simple Trigonometric Signal}
Consider the Analog signal, $ x_a(t)= cos(2\times\pi\times f\times t)$
\begin{itemize}
\item the sampled signal is: $x(n)=x_a(n)=x_a(\frac{n}{f_s})$

\end{itemize}{Time Domain Signals using Matlab\circledR}
%\lstinputlisting{Aliasing_01.m}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\subsection{Time Domain Signals}
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{DARPA-seeks-human-brain-like-computers-for-complex-signal-processing-and-data-analysis-610x400.jpg} 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\subsection{Discrete Time Domain Signals using Matlab\circledR}
%\lstinputlisting{Aliasing_02.m}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\subsection{Time Domain Signals}
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{DARPA-seeks-human-brain-like-computers-for-complex-signal-processing-and-data-analysis-610x400.jpg} 
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\subsection{Time Domain Signals}
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{basicdsp.png} 
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\subsection{Time Domain Signals}
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{basicdsp.png} 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\subsection{Time Domain Signals}
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{basicdsp.png} 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\subsection{Discrete Time Domain Signals}
%\lstinputlisting{Aliasing_03.m}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\subsection{Time Domain Signals}
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{basicdsp.png} 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\subsection{Discrete Time Domain Signals}
%\lstinputlisting{Aliasing_04.m}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\subsection{Time Domain Signals}
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{basicdsp.png} 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\subsection{Discrete Time Domain Signals}
%\lstinputlisting{Aliasing_05.m}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\subsection{Time Domain Signals}
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{basicdsp.png} 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\subsection{Discrete Time Domain Composite Signals}
%\lstinputlisting{Aliasing_06.m}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\subsection{Time Domain Signals}
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{basicdsp.png} 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\subsection{Discrete Time Domain Composite Signals}
%\lstinputlisting{Aliasing_07.m}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\subsection{Time Domain Signals}
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{basicdsp.png} 
\end{frame}

\section{Lab Report Question}
\begin{frame}{Lab Report Question \& guideline}
\subsection{Question}

Question: A digital Communication Link carries binary-coded words representing samples of an input signals of
\begin{equation}
  x_a(t)= 3 cos(100\pi t) + 0.3 sin(73 \pi t) + 6 cos(120\pi t) + .8 sin(45\pi t)
\end{equation}
\begin{itemize}
\item Now write down the required Matlab\circledR codes to get the Continuous time domain and Discrete Time domain Signal Output
\item What is the minimum sampling rate to reproduce the signals
\item How you determined this frequency
\item Take four different frequency from the given signals and verify the The Nyquist rate has to be the twice of the maximum frequency.
\item Now explain the scenarios in you own word
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```