# Beamer Theme Customization

Tags: beamer

I want to make Beamer Template  similar to this [Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcmxf.png). I have tried something like this. Now I need to customize the theme color ( I don't know which RGB combination will create something similar to the sample. Besides I need to remove one footer line (from my coding). Please suggest me some suggestion. Thank you

PS: the sample is a snapshot of a presentation. Please don't get confused with the alphabets.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{default}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\usetheme{Berlin}
\usecolortheme[rgb={0.0,0.0,0.4}]{structure}
\useoutertheme{smoothbars}
\useinnertheme{circles}
```

[image: Sample Theme]

Comment: Those with IEEE Xplore access should be able to find the original PDF at [Fundamentals of Coding and Modulation Tutorial](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5286992&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fiel5%2F5273784%2F5286960%2F05286992.pdf%3Farnumber%3D5286992).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably you will need to do some other adjustments, since no info was provided regarding inner elements (blocks, enumerated/itemized labels, etc.), but this will give you what you need and the possibility to define appropriately all other required elements:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\useoutertheme{smoothbars}
\useinnertheme{rounded}

\definecolor{mygreen1}{RGB}{0,73,44} 
\definecolor{mygreen2}{RGB}{0,140,81} 

\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=white,bg=mygreen2}
\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{fg=mygreen1,bg=mygreen2}
\setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{fg=white,bg=mygreen1}
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{bg=mygreen1,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=white,bg=mygreen2!50}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white!90!mygreen1}

\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white,bg=mygreen1}
\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{fg=white,bg=mygreen2}
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{fg=white,bg=mygreen1}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{mytheme}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.25ex,dp=3.75ex]{section in head/foot}
    \insertnavigation{\paperwidth}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}%

\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{mytheme}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\hspace*{2em}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,left]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\hspace*{2em}\insertshortsubtitle\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

\title{The Title}
\subtitle[The Subtitlein Footline]{The Subtitle}
\author{The Author}

\pgfdeclareimage[height=1cm]{logo}{dog1}%<- change dog1 for yor logo image file
\logo{\pgfuseimage{logo}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\section{Test section one}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test title}
test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\section{Test section two}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test title}
test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Can you contact me, please?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Gonzalo's is more complete (and more accurate), but since I had already started this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Darmstadt} % http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/177042/beamer-latex-customized-formats
\useoutertheme[subsection=false,footline=authortitle]{miniframes}
% RGB scaled on 0-255 scale (section 17.1.1), colors pulled from title block
\usecolortheme[RGB={44, 131, 82}]{structure}

\title{Fundamentals of X and Y}
\subtitle{Tutorial at Z 2009, Vienna, Austria}
\author{Gsomething Ksomething}
\institute{Department of Electrical Engineering \\ University of Something Comething}

\newcommand{\makeasection}{%
\subsection{A} % force dots to show up below section navigation
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}
Frame content
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}
Frame content
\end{frame}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Channels, Coding, and Capacity} \makeasection
\section{Spectral Efficiency} \makeasection
\section{Linear Block Codes} \makeasection
\section{Hard and Soft Decoding} \makeasection
\section{Fiber Capacity Estimate} \makeasection

\end{document}
```